# How can I update the Java timezone information with a IANA file newer than the one used by the latest TZupdater release?

Tags: java, timezone

The latest Time Zone Updater tool (TZUpdater) for Java contains an older timezone data file, which does not have the timezone changes for Chile scheduled for this weekend.

The [IANA Time Zone DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) has the latest information for the Chile time zone changes.

How can I use the latest IANA file (tzdata2013a.tar.gz) with TZupdater?

Answer (score 1):

If your application uses Joda Time exclusively, it appears to be possible to [update the DB](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/tz_update.html) for Joda time. But I haven't seen a sanctioned way to use a time file on the whole JVM.

However, [this SF post](https://serverfault.com/questions/368985/install-java-timezone-update) may be helpful... I would test heavily on an IDENTICAL but disposible OS/jvm system first if you go this route.

Comment: Gus, Thanks. Problem with the SF post approach is that it points to changing "Timezone definintions are exploded in the jre/lib/zi directory tree."  Those definitions are in some encoded format (ie: no the ascii used in the latest TZData files from IANA).

Comment: Not terribly surprised. Oracle/Sun probably did that to avoid people doing just what you contemplate. They may see it as a risk that they could wind up spending money trouble shooting bugs and having their product loose reputation for accuracy due to people making inappropriate updates to the files. As noted in the SF answer, it's probably best to wait for the Updater Utility if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle finally posted a note that the updated [TZupdater](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) is available:

> TZUT v1.3.54 which contains the Olson 2013a update is available now
>   for customers that have a supported ORACLE product using Java or are
>   holding a Java SE contract. Please contact your local Oracle Support
>   Office to obtain this version. For questions, please contact Oracle
>   Support.

Besides providing almost two full days notice so you have plenty of time to test, the file is not available yet on the web page and you have to contact Oracle Support to get a copy.

Well that's one way to make sure you pay for your support "Pay or Else, we are afraid somethong bad might happen to your software"